# Connecting to Apple Push Notification Server

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to connect to Apple's push notification server using my key and certificate

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert MyApp.pem -key MyApp.pem
```

I keep getting the following error. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

7495:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:358:
unable to load client certificate private key file

Answer (score 0):

You might be entering the wrong pass phrase.